# How do I split a normal distributed sample into groups of percentiles but with an additional random noise component for uncertainty?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, sampling, monte-carlo

I have a sample of students that I want to divide into smaller groups based on a their IQ but with a certain random noise component - how can I do that?

I need to cluster the best, the average and the worst students into school classes based on their IQ but with an additional random noise component that gives a small amount of mix between the classes.

How do I approach this task? I was thinking of beginning by drawing students to the class suited for the best students. Therefore the students with the highest IQ have higher probabilities to be drawn and put into this class.

I just have no idea how to permutate the sample and add the random noise.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Hans Chr.

Comment: Couldn't you simply split your observations into deciles and then add some noise to each IQ by generating a normal random variable and add the value to the IQ score or am I missing something here?

Comment: Hmm maybe I could. I'm making a Monte Carlo simulation (imitation an experiment published in a journal). The task is rather cumbersome. The simulation needs to be repeated 100 times. The class sizes are 10, 20 and 30 and the assigment of class size is random. By that I mean that if I begin with the "best" class it could be of class size 10, 20 or 30 for each simulation. The 10 or 20 or 30 best students go into this class plus the additional noise. What you propose makes sense but why do you want to  divide the observations into deciles? Isn't it enough just to add noise for each student?

Comment: What if I add the random noise to each student. Then reorder the sample based on the new IQs. Then take the "new" 10 best students into the best class (if the best class is to have a size of 10 drawn at random) - and at last remove the noise from the IQ so they get their original IQ back?

Comment: I forgot to explicitely state that I think you are nothing less than my savior if my idea to approach this (inspired by you) is appropriate.

Comment: I only suggested dividing into deciles as that is what you had mentioned in your original post.  You could certainly do the approach by adding noise to each observation and then ranking them and forming deciles.  That should get you what you need.  You would repeat this process 100 times, each time using a different normal random variable to each observation.

Comment: Of course the trick here will be setting the variance parameter in the normal random variable correctly enough so that there is a good enough mix between groups.  You might want to use the 1.5 or 2 times the variance of the sample variance calculated from your data as the variance parameter for your normal random variable.

Comment: I don't think I will form deciles. If they are just ranked after adding the noise component then I only need to draw each class from best to worst and the class size. The parameter for the noise component is luckily described in the journal it's just std. of 1 and then 0.1 as a sensivity analysis. Unless someone comes with a total different proposal in a day or something I will mark your comment as an answer.

Comment: I'll add it an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you simply split your observations into deciles and then add some noise to each IQ by generating a normal random variable and add the value to the IQ score or am I missing something here?  Of course the trick here will be setting the variance parameter in the normal random variable correctly enough so that there is a good enough mix between groups. You might want to use the 1.5 or 2 times the variance of the sample variance calculated from your data as the variance parameter for your normal random variable.

EDIT: 
I only suggested dividing into deciles as that is what you had mentioned in your original post. You could certainly do the approach by adding noise to each observation and then ranking them and forming deciles. That should get you what you need. You would repeat this process 100 times, each time using a different normal random variable to each observation.